# Magento 2.3.* - How to override ViewModel for override block?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, template, override-block, viewmodel

**Magento 2.3.***

I want to override **`ViewModel`** for the override **`block`** **(`custom.block.name`).** But the issue is my **`.phtml`** a file called from the block and it is calling on some condition. Not every time call.

My frontend **`layout.xml`** file content is,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="core.block.name">
            <block name="custom.block.name" class="Vendor\Module\Block\CoreBlock" before="-">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="custom.block.name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModel\CustomModel</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

My **`.phtml`** file render from block file. If I set the template in **`.xml`** then it is working properly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where you want to use your ViewModel. in core.block.name or custom.block.name's phtml file?

Comment: `custom.block.name`.

Comment: your custom.block.name assigned in other xml or?

Comment: No, it is in the same XML file. And I tried so many time as your answer but not working.

Comment: Please update your full xml in question.

Comment: Question updated. Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105150/discussion-between-dhaduk-mitesh-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, You need to set `custom.block.name` as `referenceBlock`. Try to use this below code :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block name="custom.block.name" class="Vendor\Module\Block\CoreBlock" before="-">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="custom.block.name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\ViewModel\CustomModel</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**NOTE:** Replace the argument name(`viewModel`) with your core ViewModel Name.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/CoreBlock.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class CoreBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Module::temp.phtml';
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/ViewModel/CustomModel.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\ViewModel;

class CustomModel implements \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface
{

    public function getYourFunction()
    {
        $text = "test";
        return $text;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/temp.phtml

```
echo $block->getData('viewModel')->getYourFunction();
```

**NOTE:** Replace `viewModel` with your argument name of `customer_account.xml`.

Output :

[image]